# Select Ticket records from one table that are associated with a Customer or the Customers children in another table

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say that I have a table containing all of my Customer records.
Each record has a unique ID, a name and possibly a parent record ID.

(In case it makes a difference a parent can have multiple children but children can only have one parent. There's also no grandfather records, so a parent may not have a parent and children may not have children)

**Customers**

```
+-----+------------+----------+
| ID  |    Name    | ParentID |
+-----+------------+----------+
| 100 | Customer A |          |
| 101 | Customer B |          |
| 102 | Customer C |      100 |
| 103 | Customer D |      100 |
| 104 | Customer E |      101 |
+-----+------------+----------+
```

As you can see from this example I have 5 unique Customer records, with C & D being children of A and E a child of B.

Now I have a table containing all of the Tickets these Customers raise.
Each ticket has a unique ID, a description and a parent customer ID.

**Tickets**

```
+-----+-------------+----------+
| ID  | Description | ParentID |
+-----+-------------+----------+
| 500 | Ticket A    |      100 |
| 501 | Ticket B    |      100 |
| 502 | Ticket C    |      102 |
| 503 | Ticket D    |      102 |
| 504 | Ticket E    |      103 |
| 505 | Ticket F    |      101 |
| 506 | Ticket G    |      104 |
| 507 | Ticket H    |      101 |
+-----+-------------+----------+
```

**Goal**

- I will have been given a Customer ID and need to select all Tickets belonging to this record.
- If the record has children I also need the tickets belonging to these records.
- If the record is a child I'm not interested in its parent.

**Example 1**

I'm given the ID 100. This is Customer A and has two children, C & D.
As the results of my select I would expect the following:

- Ticket A - Directly belongs to ID 100
- Ticket B - Directly belongs to ID 100
- Ticket C - Belongs to ID 102, a child of 100
- Ticket D - Belongs to ID 102, a child of 100
- Ticket E - Belongs to ID 103, a child of 100

**Example 2**

I'm given ID 104. This is Customer E, a child record.
As the results of my select I would expect the following:

- Ticket G - Directly belongs to ID 104

I would not expect anything further as the record is a child and therefore has no children and I'm not looking upwards at parent records.

**Where I'm stuck...**

Getting Tickets belonging to one ID is easy:

```
SELECT
  tickets.Description

FROM
  Tickets AS tickets

LEFT JOIN
  Customers AS customers ON
  tickets.ParentID = customers.ID

WHERE
  customers.ID = 100
```

I'm stuck getting the Tickets belonging to children.

It seems like I'd first have to request the Customer belonging to the given ID, then fetch all child Customers where the ParentID matched the given ID, then finally request Tickets belonging to any of these records.

Unfortunately I haven't got the faintest idea where to start and require some help.

In case it's relevant I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Move `customers.ID = 100` to the `ON` clause to get true left join result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use a [recursive common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to iterate through the ancestry and get all related records:

```
DECLARE @CustomerID INT = 100;

-- SAMPLE DATA FOR CUSTOMERS
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255), ParentID INT);
INSERT @Customers (ID, Name, ParentID)
VALUES
    (100, 'Customer A', NULL),
    (101, 'Customer B', NULL),
    (102, 'Customer C', 100),
    (103, 'Customer D', 100),
    (104, 'Customer E', 101);

-- SAMPLE DATA FOR TICKETS
DECLARE @Tickets TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255), ParentID INT);
INSERT @Tickets (ID, Name, ParentID)
VALUES
    (500, 'Ticket A', 100),
    (501, 'Ticket B', 100),
    (502, 'Ticket C', 102),
    (503, 'Ticket D', 102),
    (504, 'Ticket E', 103),
    (505, 'Ticket F', 101),
    (506, 'Ticket G', 104),
    (507, 'Ticket H', 101);

-- USE RECURSIVE CTE TO LOOP THROUGH HIERARCHY AND GET ALL ANCESTORS
WITH RecursiveCustomers AS
(   SELECT  c.ID, c.Name, c.ParentID
    FROM    @Customers AS c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  rc.ID, rc.Name, c.ParentID
    FROM    RecursiveCustomers AS rc
            INNER JOIN @Customers AS c 
                ON rc.ParentID = c.ID
)
SELECT  t.ID, t.Name, t.ParentID
FROM    @Tickets AS t
        INNER JOIN RecursiveCustomers AS rc
            ON rc.ID = t.ParentID
WHERE   rc.ParentID = @CustomerID OR (rc.ID = @CustomerID AND rc.ParentID IS NULL);
```

**RESULT FOR 100**

```
+-----+-------------+----------+
| ID  | Description | ParentID |
+-----+-------------+----------+
| 500 | Ticket A    |      100 |
| 501 | Ticket B    |      100 |
| 502 | Ticket C    |      102 |
| 503 | Ticket D    |      102 |
| 504 | Ticket E    |      103 |
+-----+-------------+----------+
```

**RESULT FOR 104**

```
+-----+-------------+----------+
| ID  | Description | ParentID |
+-----+-------------+----------+
| 506 | Ticket G    |      104 |
+-----+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thank you so much. I'll go and teach myself exactly why this works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select tickets.Description

FROM
  Tickets AS tickets
LEFT JOIN
 Customers  ON
 customers.ID= tickets.ParentID 
OR 
customers.ParentID =tickets.ParentID 
WHERE
  Tickets.ParentID = 100
```

Comment: This returned "Ticket A; Ticket A; Ticket A; Ticket B; Ticket B; Ticket B;" for 6 rows which is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Although the demo provided by GarethD worked fine in the demonstration (and at first I thought it worked on the live data) I got weird results in the live data where tickets belonging to the parent were repeated 4 times each although rows related to children only appeared once.

In my ignorance and with an inability to fix said issue I've used a different approach that works fine so I thought I'd leave it here as an alternative.

First I select the parent and child records and store them in a table:

```
DECLARE @CUSTOMERS TABLE (
  ID BIGINT,
  PARENTID BIGINT,
  NAME VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO @CUSTOMERS(ID, PARENTID, NAME)
SELECT
  id,
  parent_id,
  name
FROM [customer_table]
WHERE id = '194' OR parent_id = '194';
```

Now I can join to this table as normal to select the correct Tickets:

```
SELECT 
  customer.[NAME],
  ticket.[id],
  ticket.[description],

FROM [ticket_table] AS ticket

LEFT JOIN @CUSTOMERS AS customer
ON ticket.[id] = customer.[ID]

WHERE
  ticket.[id] = customer.[ID];
```

This produces the correct number of tickets and seems fast enough. Hope it helps someone.